# Can admin edit a user’s “Manage Account Access” (ical)

Tags: mac-osx-server, xserve, ical, caldav

As a server administrator, can I edit a user's "Manage Account Access" settings. This is where a user sets who can see their calendar. Whenever we add a new user, we have to go to every person's computer and add the new user's account to this. It would be great if I could do this server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on Mac OS X 10.6 server you can use the command:

```
  calendarserver_manage_principals
```

to manage calendar delegations for users.

---

E.g. adding 'user1' as read proxy for 'user2':

```
sudo calendarserver_manage_principals --add-read-proxy users:user1 users:user2
```

---

More at:

```
man calendarserver_manage_principals
```

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3897